# LabVIEW: How to dynamically create combobox items during run time

Tags: combobox, labview

I would like to generate combobox items dynamically during run time. I have a combobox called Camera and say if I have 10 cameras connected then I want to name each camera as "Camera_0", "Camera_1", "Camera_2"..., and "Camera_9" and display them in the combo box.

I want to leverage a for loop to append a string to store each camera string name in an array so that I can display in the combobox.

[image: storing items to combo box]

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

Build an array of strings first and then write to the "Strings[]" property of the combo box using a reference or a property node.

[image]

Edit: original snippet was wonky due to the property node. Just wire your combo box reference to the "Combo Box" node there and you're all set.

Comment: I see I got it. One more question. What is the icon connected to the right side of CmbBox ? What is it for ?

Comment: Close reference. By the way, the snippet I attached can be dragged into a block diagram of a vi and the code will be automatically created. There you can interact with it any way you like. But it has to be kept in the original png format.

Comment: There is no need -- ever -- to close references that are parts of a VI. That means controls, panels, diagrams, nodes, etc. Open or close them as you wish, but the items stay around as long as the VI stays around. Calling Close Reference on a control refnum is a no-op. Close Reference is only necessary for items that actually are in control of their own lifetimes... which is basically ALL other types of refnums that aren't parts of a VI. :-) I've asked NI to make the wire break if you use Close Ref, but that change would break existing VIs, so it stays as a no-op.

Comment: @srm:you're absolutely right but I'd rather close a hundred that didn't need it than to leave one open that did. ["The simplest rule is close all references.  It may not be necessary but it won't hurt."](https://forums.ni.com/t5/LabVIEW/Close-Reference/m-p/1994953#M657408)

Comment: @Dave_St I wish it was such an easy call. Many control-refnum-heavy programs end up spending considerable energy collecting references into arrays or bundling them with other data... all that unnecessary tracking can be a performance burden on the app.